# Flutter ListTile in ListView grey in release iOS

Tags: flutter, list, listview, tile

When I build my Flutter project in release on iOS, when a ListTile appears inside the ListView I get a grey container instead of the actual listTile.
I suspect it has to do with the size of the ListView.
[image: ListView]

Answer (score 0):

Connect the phone to the laptop and run the following in the terminal

> flutter run --release

And then open this screen. I am sure you will find something in terminal

Comment: I can't run it on release because Xcode is in a newer version than my phone. Xcode gets an error: failed to prepare the device for development.

Answer (score -1):

````
                                  SizedBox(
                                  width: 100.w,
                                  child: Obx(() {
                                    return ListView.builder(
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        itemCount: splitBillingController
                                            .splitUsers.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                                          return Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                vertical: 8),
                                            child: splitBillingController
                                                    .isLoading.value
                                                ? const Center(
                                                    child:
                                                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                      color: primaryColor,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                : Dismissible(
                                                    direction: DismissDirection
                                                        .endToStart,
                                                    confirmDismiss:
                                                        (direction) async {
                                                      // return null;
                                                      return await splitBillingController
                                                          .removeSplitter(
                                                              splitBillingController
                                                                          .splitUsers[
                                                                      index]![
                                                                  "userId"]);
                                                    background: Container(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                              .symmetric(
                                                          horizontal: 30),
                                                      alignment:
                                                          AlignmentDirectional
                                                              .centerEnd,
                                                      color: Colors.red,
                                                      child: const Icon(
                                                        Icons.delete,
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    key: Key(
                                                        splitBillingController
                                                                .splitUsers[
                                                            index]!["userId"]),
                                                    child: ListTile(
                                                      textColor: buttonColor,
                                                      selected:
                                                          splitBillingController
                                                                      .splitUsers[
                                                                  index]![
                                                              "isUnlocked"],
                                                      selectedColor:
                                                          Colors.white,
                                                      selectedTileColor:
                                                          buttonColor,
                                                      onTap: () async {
                                                        await splitBillingController
                                                            .approveUser(
                                                                splitBillingController
                                                                        .splitUsers[
                                                                    index]);
                                                      },
                                                      shape:
                                                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius
                                                                .circular(24),
                                                      ),
                                                      tileColor: Colors.white,
                                                      // const Icon(Icons.credit_card),
                                                      leading:
                                                          CircularProfileAvatar(
                                                        splitBillingController
                                                                .splitUsers[
                                                            index]!["photo"],
                                                        radius: 20,
                                                        borderWidth: 0,
                                                        placeHolder: (context,
                                                                url) =>
                                                            SvgPicture.asset(
                                                          'assets/images/armadillo.svg',
                                                          height: 20,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      title: Text(
                                                        splitBillingController
                                                                .splitUsers[
                                                            index]!["userName"],
                                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                mainFontBold),
                                                      ),
                                                      subtitle: const Text(
                                                          "Passenger"),
                                                      trailing: Text(
                                                        "${splitBillingController.splitUsers[index]!["amount"].toStringAsFixed(2)}€",
                                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 22,
                                                          fontFamily:
                                                              mainFontBold,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                          );
                                        });
                                  }),
                                ),```
````

Comment: Is this an answer or an update to the question? In the former case, please read [answer] and then [edit] to clarify. In the latter case, please delete this and edit your question instead.